# HowTo Get Rendered Image from WPF Image Control

Tags: wpf, rendertargetbitmap, rendertransform

Each **WPF Image Control** has **RenderTransform** Property that sets **Scale**, **Skew**, **Rotate** and many more Transformation to Images. After Calling **RenderTransform** Property, How to get Rendered Image into the **BitmapImage** or **RenderTargetBitmap** Class or Any other class?

This is my Code:

```
Dim InImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("My Image Path"))

Dim TG As New TransformGroup
TG.Children.Add(New RotateTransform(190))

Dim MyImg As New Image
MyImg.Source = InImage
MyImg.RenderTransform = TG

'Here i need get Transformed Image into a BitmapImage or RenderTargetBitmap Variable  or Any other class variable.
```

Comment: No need for the TransformGroup. Just set `MyImg.RenderTransform = New RotateTransform(190)`. Then call `Measure` and `Arrange` on `MyImg`, and finally create a RenderTargetBitmap and call its `Render` method with `MyImg` as parameter.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks `Measure` and `Arrange` is worked properly. but now the problem is that after some rotation, some part of Rotated Image not drawing. how to solve that?

Comment: Use an appropriate rectangle (with negative X and Y) in Arrange. You may also try LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform.

Comment: When i add **Rotated Image** to Canvas, some part of image which is placed on Left or Top of canvas, will not draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pity that `TransformedBitmap` does not support rotation with angle other than any multiple of 90 degs (that means we can only rotate 90, 180, 270, ...). Thinking about which objects we can put in a bitmap and apply some `Transform`? Well we have `DrawingGroup`, `DrawingVisual`, `ImageBrush`, `UIElement` and via `DrawingContext`.

- Using `DrawingGroup`, we have to put in an `ImageDrawing` and apply the transform via the `Transform` property of the `DrawingGroup`. Then we have to use a `DrawingImage`, set the `Drawing` property to the `DrawingGroup`.
- Using `DrawingVisual`, we have to open a `DrawingContext`, use the `DrawImage` method after pushing some transform. Then we may have to use `RenderTargetBitmap` by passing the `DrawingVisual` in the `Render` method.
- Using `UIElement` (like your idea about using `Image` control as the medium), we have to render the image on the `UIElement`. So an `Image` control suits this best. Every `UIElement` has a `Transform` property allowing us to add whatever transform. At last we also have to use a `RenderTargetBitmap` by passing the `UIElement` in the `Render` method.
- Using `ImageBrush`, we have to set the `ImageSource` property to a `BitmapImage`. Then we can use the `Transform` or `RelativeTransform` property to apply some transform. After that  we have to use a `DrawingImage`. Create a simple `GeometryDrawing` using the `ImageBrush` as its Brush, and a `RectangleGeometry` as its Geometry. Finally we just need to set this `GeometryDrawing` to the `Drawing` property of the `DrawingImage`. The output is the `DrawingImage`. I would like to use this approach to write the code here:

  ```
  Dim InImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("My Image Path"))
  Dim ImgBrush As New ImageBrush(InImage)
  ImgBrush.Viewport = New Rect(0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8)
  ImgBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.RelativeToBoundingBox
  Dim Rotating As New RotateTransform(190)
  Rotating.CenterX = 0.5
  Rotating.CenterY = 0.5
  ImgBrush.RelativeTransform = Rotating

  Dim ImgSize As New Rect(0,0,300,400)
  Dim DrawImage As New DrawingImage()
  DrawImage.Drawing = New GeometryDrawing(ImgBrush, null, ImgSize)
  ```

Note about the `"My Image Path"`. I've found out that using a `Relative` image would not work if you don't have any Image folder at the same level with the built exe file. If you don't want to deploy some image folder together with your application, you can add your image as a ***Resource***. To refer to an image added as a Resource in code behind, you have to use a special kind of path:

```
pack://application:,,,/Your_Relative_Image_Path
```

Note that to be sure your image is added as a Resource, try right clicking on the image (under the Projects treeview), select *Properties* in the popup menu, then look into the ***Build Action*** field, it should be ***Resource***.

Also note about the `ImgBrush.Viewport`, setting it appropriately will prevent the image from being cut off (that's because the transformed image is rotated). It depends on the `ImgSize` and how much degree you rotate.

Comment: after running your code, this error occurred: **Transform must be a combination of scales, flips, and 90 degree rotations**.  it seams that the TransformedBitmap class dose not support full rotation or skew.

Comment: @GiGatR00n yes, `TransformedBitmap` does not support rotation other than multiples of 90degs. See my updated answer for another approach (in fact we have many approaches, I just picked a one).

Comment: @GiGatR00n you're welcome. The logic is simple but you may need time to tweak it with some experiment. The most obvious/intuitive way is  using `TramsfomedBitmap`, however as we know it does not work in your case, although other kinds of transform are well supported.

Comment: yeah, `TransformedBitmap` not work in my program cuz i need 0-360 degree rotation. im using `DrawingGroup` and `ImageBrush`. `DrawingGroup` works properly. Thanks.